# How to hide "Include file in display" in File Field?

Tags: 7, files

I'm using File Field in Drupal 7 to let users upload files, but after uploading there is a choice for users to let the file be included in display or not (radio button with "Include file in display" description). Now I want to remove this choice, because I need all of the files display for download, OR at least hide this for non-admin users. What should I do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set that in the field's settings page.

```
Structure > Content Types > [your content type] > Manage Fields > Edit [your file field]
```

You will see settings for the `Enable Display Field` Option. The caveat is that if you already have data in this file field, unchecking this may not have an effect.

(See my screen capture)[image]